# char retorna numero digitado invalido como opção

Tags: c, while, switch

opa boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um menu em que a opção digitada é um char, o mesmo retorna o default corretamente após digitar uma letra, no entanto, meu switch possui 7 opções de case ('1', '2',...,'7'), o problema é que quando digito um número inválido como por exemplo: 22, ele retorna o case '2' (não sei o que ocorre com o outro 2), sendo que deveria retornar o default, alguém pode me ajudar a identificar o erro? (não estou conseguindo pensar no que poderia ser).
segue o código para analise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    char op;
    char opc = 's';
    char *diaSemana[7] = {"\n1. Segunda-feira", "\n2. Terca-feira", "\n3. Quarta-feira", "\n4. Quinta-feira", "\n5. Sexta-feira", "\n6. Sabado", "\n7. Domingo"};
    
    while (opc == 's') {
        
        printf("\n------Menu------\n");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", diaSemana[i]);
        }

        printf("\nEntre com uma opcao.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &op);
        switch(op) {
            case '1':           
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: branca.\n", diaSemana[0]);
            break;
            case '2':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: verde.\n", diaSemana[1]);        
            break;
            case '3':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: azul.\n", diaSemana[2]);     
            break;
            case '4':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: amarela.\n", diaSemana[3]);      
            break;
            case '5':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: vermelha.\n", diaSemana[4]);     
            break;
            case '6':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: cinza.\n", diaSemana[5]);        
            break;
            case '7':   
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: rosa.\n", diaSemana[6]);     
            break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalida.\n");
            break;
        }
                printf("Deseja fazer uma nova operacao? (s/n)\n");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%c", &opc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como você está lendo um único caractere (`scanf("%c", &op);`) ao digitar `23` ele considerará apenas o `2`. Tente com `9` ou `A` que será apresentada opção inválida.

Comment: tem como fazer com que ele nao considere 23 ou qualquer outro numero como 10, 11 e etc, nesse caso? se nao tiver, agradeço a ajuda mesmo assim.

Comment: Você está lendo um único caractere. Se quiser ler uma cadeia de caracteres então trabalhe com string.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é você ler a linha inteira e verificar se ela tem mais de um caractere o que é considerado um erro. Se tiver apenas um caractere o seu switch/case identificará se é válido ou não.

Comment: então significa que %c faz a leitura de apenas UM caractere? se eu usar %s, qual a diferença?

Comment: tentei fazer o que você disse trabalhando com string, mas vi na internet que não é possível utilizando switch, apenas se fosse if..else, se esse for o único caminho, prefiro não mexer. ainda sou leiga em c e estou tentando aprender, valeu

Comment: Com %s você pode ler uma sequencia de caracteres.

Comment: Leia como string. Se o tamanho da string > 1 então erro. pegue o primeiro (e único) caractere da string e utilize em seu comando switch.

Comment: Encerrando por aqui devido às regras do site.

Comment: ok, obrigada. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está uma possibilidade baseada no seu código, mas existem outras alternativas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    
    char op[50];
    char opc = 's';
    char *diaSemana[7] = {"\n1. Segunda-feira", "\n2. Terca-feira", "\n3. Quarta-feira", "\n4. Quinta-feira", "\n5. Sexta-feira", "\n6. Sabado", "\n7. Domingo"};
    
    while (opc == 's') {
        
        printf("\n------Menu------\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            printf("%s\n", diaSemana[i]);
        }

        printf("\nEntre com uma opcao.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", op);
        while (strlen(op) > 1) {
            printf("Múltiplos caracteres.\nEntre com uma opcao.\n");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", op);
        }
        switch(op[0]) {
            case '1':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: branca.\n", diaSemana[0]);
            break;
            case '2':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: verde.\n", diaSemana[1]);
            break;
            case '3':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: azul.\n", diaSemana[2]);
            break;
            case '4':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: amarela.\n", diaSemana[3]);
            break;
            case '5':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: vermelha.\n", diaSemana[4]);
            break;
            case '6':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: cinza.\n", diaSemana[5]);
            break;
            case '7':
                printf("\nDia da semana:%s\nCor da camisa: rosa.\n", diaSemana[6]);
            break;
            default:
                printf("Opcao invalida.\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Deseja fazer uma nova operacao? (s/n)\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &opc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```